# Trying understand python class here with this string manipulation script, it's giving me error

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, inheritance, instance

So I have the following code in python 2.7.  with main.py and a stringmanipulation.py containing the class

In my main.py I have

```
import stringmanipulation  

testvalue = "[323232 , 232323]"
testvalue.stringmanipulation.modify()
```

In my stringmanipulation.py I have

```
class modify (object):
    def __init__(self):
         extract = self.split('[', 1)[1].split(']')[0]
         extract.split(", ")
         self.x = extract[0]
         self.y = extract[1]
```

Now the error I get is

```
testvalue.stringmanipulation.modify()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'stringmanipulation'
```

If I do it the other way

```
newvariable = stringmanipulation.modify(testvalue)
```

This code works fine

Comment: Are you trying to code up a new language where classes are automagically bound to arbitrary objects?

Comment: What is the better way to do this?

Comment: What you call "the other way" is the only way to do what you are doing. It's not clear why you expect the first version to work.

Comment: with `testvalue = "[323232 , 232323]"` you have normal string which doesn't have `stringmanipulation` - what did you expect ?

Comment: I think I am getting this. So testvalue.stringmanipulation.modify() can only work if testvalue was an instance of the modify class?

Comment: No.  `testvalue.stringmanipulation.modify()` can only work if `testvalue` is an object with an attribute named `stringmanipulation` which was an object that has a method named `modify`, although what 'work' means in this context is unclear.